# "NameError: uninitialized constant UserAgent" when using Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, watir, irb

I'm new to ruby, I seem to have successfully installed `watir-webdriver` and `webdriver-user-agent` gems, but when I was trying to follow the instructions [here](http://watirwebdriver.com/mobile-devices/) I've stumbled.  How to proceed?

```
>> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
>> require 'webdriver-user-agent'
=> true
>> driver = UserAgent.driver(:browser => :chrome, :agent => :iphone, :orientation => :landscape)
NameError: uninitialized constant UserAgent
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `Webdriver::UserAgent`

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  Is there a way to see what names are in scope (similar to `whos` in ipython)?  I checked `local_variables` but `Webdriver` wasn't there..